# What is the bash command on Ubuntu to list all the signals?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, signals

Is there a command to view all the signals on a Ubuntu machine?
I'm using a bash shell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `trap` builtin:

```
trap -l
```

From `help trap`:

> `-l` print a list of signal names and their corresponding numbers

Answer (score 7):

You can use `kill -l` to obtain a list (same as `trap -l`, at least on my system).

This command can also be used with an argument, such as `kill -l SIGNAL`, where SIGNAL is either a signal number (in which case the command will output its name), or a signal name (such as SIGHUP), in which case the command will output its number.

Comment: Great answer.  One more point: `kill -l SIGHUP` works the same way as `kill -l HUP`.  So, `SIG` part is optional.

Answer (score 3):

All signals are listed in the [`signal(7)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/7/signal).

```
man 7 signal
```

Comment: Is it possible without using man? I require a single shell command that lists all the signals?